# Outlook Web-Add In, Send Feature

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I see the sample https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send

What I am wondering, I have a requirement to record the body of the email to the as a message the recorder is the user sending the message and message is attached to the user that has that email address.

Problem: **Person sending the email must be authenticated or prompt to authenticate.**

When sending, can a dialog pop-up to authenticate the user?  The example does not show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authentication, try using [the displayDialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). Part of the documentation for that API discusses authentication flow.

Linked from that documentation is [an example add-in that uses the displayDialog API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example). An On Send add-in is similar to an ExecuteFunction add-in command, which is one of the examples included there.